# Replacing part of a string and adding to it not producing the intended results

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, lua, filenames

I'm working on my first script: trying to grab all filenames from a folder (titled as `Thing_XXfilename.png`), removing some initial characters (`Thing_XX`) aswell as their extention and then inserting them one by one into a repeating line of code.

I've tried dozens of variations but, for some reason that eludes me, the output is iterating through the characters of each original filename (no effect from the replace) and inserting them one after another into the code.

```
nf0 = 'Events.OnGameStart.Add( function ()\n\tif MyScript then\n'
nf1 = ' if MyScript.Thing.XX'
nf2 = ' then\n\t\telse\n\t\t\tMyScript.Thing.XX'
nf3 = ' = {"Misc.", nil, nil, "'
nf4 = '", "MyMod.XX'
nf5 = '", "Thing_XX'
nf6 = '", nil, nil, nil};\n\t\t\tend\n'
nfn = ' end\nend)'

import os

f = open("textures.lua", "w")
f.write(nf0)
for files in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Myuser\Textures'):
    for filename in files:
        line = filename.replace('Thing_XX', '')
        line = filename.replace('.png', '')
        f.write(nf1 + filename + nf2 + filename + nf3 + filename + nf4 + filename + nf5 + filename + nf6)
f.write(nfn)
f.close()
```

This should be producing:

```
if MyScript.Thing.XXfilename1 then
        else
            MyScript.Thing.XXfilename1 = {"Misc.", nil, nil, "filename1", "MyMod.XXfilename1", "Thing_XXfilename1", nil, nil, nil};
            end
```

But results in this instead:

```
if MyScript.Thing.XXT then
        else
            MyScript.Thing.XXT = {"Misc.", nil, nil, "T", "MyMod.XXT", "Thing_XXT", nil, nil, nil};
            end
```

The letter 'T' that shows up here, being the first letter of the first filename (and then repeated ad nauseam for each letter of all filenames).

Comment: Are you sure that `C:\Users\Myuser\Textures` isn't an empty directory?

Comment: Absolutely! And i have a 6MB textures.lua that Python spit out to prove it :-P Though i should be using a relative path like %username%, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You should try to use python's string formatting functionality. It will make your code a lot easier to read.

Comment: @veggie1: R Nar beat me to it. Glad he did, i'm not sure how to use that formatting... i'll look for that option next time.

Comment: next time, just highlight all the code you want formatted and press ctrl+K :)

Comment: thanks for the tip! hoping to have better code to use it on by then ;)

Comment: in terms of your code, you have a nested for loop where `for files in os.listdir(path)` already iterates through your dirs. that means that `for filename in files` is actually iterating through a `files` string. take out the nested for loop. also, use string formatting haha

Answer (score 1):

You are using a double-loop where you just need one loop.

```
f = open("textures.lua", "w")
f.write(nf0)
for filename in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Myuser\Textures'):
    line = filename.replace('Thing_XX', '')
    line = line.replace('.png', '')   ## also need to change this 
    f.write(nf1 + line + nf2 + line + nf3 + line + nf4 + line + nf5 + line + nf6)
```

Comment: I knew it would be an obvious mistake! But that is shamefully evident!!! Thank you. It works! :D

Comment: Though there's still one problem: the replace isn't working, full original filenames are being writen containing both the initial Thing_XX and the extension :(

Comment: had to make an edit...you replace logic wasn't quite right (double check the code above)

Comment: No, sorry. That doesn't do it either. It's so close, it's nerve-wrecking!

Comment: oh, woops, sorry, one more fix...should be "line" instead of "filename" in the write statement

Comment: I think i got it. it has to be `filename = filename.replace` both times! Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

base_string = (
    'something something {filename}\n'
    'something else {filename} blah blah')

output = ''

f = open("textures.lua", "w")
for filename in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Myuser\Textures'):
    filename.replace('Thing_XX', '')
    filename.replace('.png', '')
    output += base_string.format(filename=filename)

output = (
    'top of file\n'
    '{output}\n'
    'bottom of file').format(output=output))

f.write(output)
f.close()
```

Comment: I'll play with that for the sake of learning, since i'm not fully understanding all those statements, but gariepy nailed it already and it doesn't require such a large rewrite. Can i bother you with a follow-up question: how do i format the 'C:\Users\%Username%' environment variable so the % operator doesn't mess it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the users home directory:

```
os.getenv("HOME")
```

For example

```
print os.getenv("HOME")
```

will return

```
c:\users\username
```

Comment: as in `path = os.getenv("HOME") + "\textures"` and then `os.listdir(r 'path')`?